# R sum multi columns in df technique

Tags: r

I try to get sum for each of the Flags 1-3 in my dataframe and keep same column names, so I get single row , but looks like I missing some df/Numeric conversion here, can you please advice , not sure whey I get dim(dfs) = NULL??

```
df <- data.frame(label=2017, F1=1:4, F2=2:5, F3=3:6)
df

dfs <-            c( max(df$label), sum(df$F1), sum(df$F2), sum(df$F3)) 
#dfs <- data.frame(c( max(df$label), sum(df$F1), sum(df$F2), sum(df$F3)) )
dfs
str(dfs)
dim(dfs)

colnames(dfs) <-c('Label', 'F1','F2','F3')
## Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Label", "F1", "F2", "F3")) : 
##    attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Comment: Your `c()` creates a vector, not a data frame. If you use `as.data.frame(t(dfs))` you'll be able to set the column names. You might also be interested in `colSums()`, or maybe even the [How to sum variables by group? R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061).

Comment: Thanks much Gregor!!!   Case solved. **I can't see a place to give a points to correct answers, is something changed on SOverflow ? Best. M

Comment: aggregate(. ~ label, df, sum)   ## this is perfect, Tx again G!

Comment: @KevinArseneau I agree that this kind of question most likely has already been asked several times on SO but there must be better dupe targets, IMHO. The linked question does only aggregate one column while here the OP wants to aggregate multiple columns simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Your `c()` creates a vector, not a data frame. If you convert your vector to a one-row data frame with `as.data.frame(t(dfs))`, you'll be able to set the column names.

You might also be interested in colSums(), or maybe even the [How to sum variables by group? R-FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)